# Click to open a new canvas panel with an image- tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I want to click on a picture in the canvas in order to open a new canvas in which there is another picture and for some reason the new canvas opens and the picture does not appear anyone might know how to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("root")
root.geometry('800x550')

canvas = Canvas(root,
                bg='white',
                bd=5,
                relief='groove',
                height=500,
                width=700,
                )
canvas.place(x=80, y=0)

def press_to_open(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    new_img = Image.open("images/back_p.png")
    w, h = new_img.size

    if x >= 3 and x <= 3 + w and y >= 3 and y <= 3 + h:
        canvas2 = Canvas(canvas,
                         bg='white',
                         bd=2,
                         relief='groove',
                         height=120,
                         width=250,
                         )
        canvas2.place(x=100, y=90)
        resize_text = Label(canvas2, text="Resize the image:", bg="white", font=('Bodoni MT', 
        12))
        resize_text.place(x=65, y=10)

        img = PhotoImage("images/x.png")
        x_button = Button(canvas2, command=canvas2.destroy, bd=0, image=img)
        x_button.pack()
        canvas2.create_window(10, 10, window=x_button, height=65, width=65)

def destroy_window(event):
    global new_label
    new_label.destroy()

color_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/back_p.png"))
label = Label(canvas, image=color_img)
label.place(x=10, y=10)
root.bind('<Button-1>', press_to_open)
root.bind('<Button-3>', destroy_window)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `img = PhotoImage("images/x.png")` should be `img = PhotoImage(file="images/x.png")`. After fixing it, it will have same issue as this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function).